# R Mutate and Count Backwards with a group

Tags: r, group-by, count, dplyr

For the following dataframe:

```
A<-c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D')
A<-data.frame(A)
```

How do you add a column to count backwards, each time the group for 'A' changes....as in:
Desired Output:

desired_output<-c(3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1)
desired_output<-data.frame(desired_output)

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rev` on the `row_number()` after grouping by 'A'

```
library(dplyr)
A <- A %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(desired = rev(row_number())) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 2
#   A     desired
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 A           3
# 2 A           2
# 3 A           1
# 4 B           5
# 5 B           4
# 6 B           3
# 7 B           2
# 8 B           1
# 9 C           4
#10 C           3
#11 C           2
#12 C           1
#13 D           6
#14 D           5
#15 D           4
#16 D           3
#17 D           2
#18 D           1
```

---

Or another option is create the sequence with `:` to 1

```
A %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(desired = n():1) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks for this - so you are adding a column that counts from the 'n' number of elements in the group backwards to 1...then starts again. Thats great - appreciated.